# How to find a general solution as 2nd order linear differential equation is given with zero value of RHS and only one particular solution is known

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The below equation is of 2nd order linear differential equation.

$$  \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2}-\frac{  \left( 2x-6 \right)   }{  \left( x-2 \right)   } \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{  \left( x-4 \right)   }{  \left( x-2 \right)   } y=0 \tag{1}  $$

$$  \frac{  e^{ x }   }{  x-2  }~\text{is known as one of the solution(s) of this ODE}  $$

I want to derive a general solution $~  y\left(x\right)  ~$ of eqn1 .

I've read the book to derive it however seemingly the book only handles cases of ODE as RHS of 2nd order linear differntial equation is nonzero or as 2 particular solutions are given in a problem statement.

So, this case of eqn1, RHS of the equation is $~ 0 ~$ and only one particular solution is given.

Which method can I use here to find out the general solution?

Can anyone tell me it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $y_1$ is a known solution to homogeneous linear DE $y''+p(x)y'+g(x)y=0$.

Finding a second, linearly independent solution is often achieved by assuming $y_2(x)=v(x)y_1(x)$ where $v(x)$ is an unknown function that needs to be determined.

Plugging into our DE and simplifying give us $$v''+\Big[2\big(\ln(y_1)\big)'+p(x)\Big]v'=0$$ In your case $p(x)=-\frac{2x-6}{x-2}$ and $y_1(x)=\frac{e^x}{x-2}$ which yields $v''=0$ and so $v(x)=ax+b$ for some constants $a,b$. The general solution is $$y=c_1y_1(x)+c_2(ax+b)y_1(x)$$ Rearranging terms we can write this as $$y=C_1\Big(\frac{e^x}{x-2}\Big)+C_2\Big(\frac{xe^x}{x-2}\Big)$$ where $C_1=c_1+c_2b$ and $C_2=c_2a$